# How do I add commands that allow me to start and stop a discord bot without completely ending its process (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to create a discord bot, the purpose of the bot is to output a specific string when a specific word is detected.

I have already figured out how to do that and it works just fine, but what I am really struggling with is how to give the bot start and stop commands that would look like this: !start, !stop. I also wanted to output a message when each command is triggered in order to let users know that it has worked.

any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
import os
import discord
from keep_on import keep_on
bot_token = os.environ['TOKEN']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user} is online'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  sentWord = message.content
  CSentWord = sentWord.upper()
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if "SORRY" in CSentWord:
    await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
  if "S_O_R_R_Y" in CSentWord:
    await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
  if "S.O.R.R.Y" in CSentWord:
    await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
  if "S|O|R|R|Y" in CSentWord:
    await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))

keep_on()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code?

Comment: I edited my original post and added the code I have so far, if you are wondering why it is Joey Tribbiani it's because I came up with the idea for the bot when I was bored lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to have a (global) boolean variable `enabled` which is toggled to `True` when receiving the command `!start`, and to `False` on the `!stop` command. Then when checking for other commands than `!start` and `!stop`, first check the value of `enabled` and execute the commands only if `enabled` is `True`. Sending a message when receiving one of these two commands is also straightforward.

This can look like something like this:

```py
enabled = False

# Method called when the bot receives a message
async def on_message(message):
    global enabled
    
    if message.content == "!start":
        enabled = True
        await message.channel.send("Bot is on.")
    elif message.content == "!stop":
        enabled = False
        await message.channel.send("Bot is off.")
    elif enabled:
        # Do whatever is done when the bot receives a message normally
        # ...
```

Though using `global` is a known bad practice, but this would work as a first approach.

Comment: `message.channel.send` are coroutines, they should be awaited

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thanks, I forgot them. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add some sort of global check, and you have many options to do it. E.g, you could handle the check in a `on_command` event, or even at the bot level with a `bot.check` decorator.

Then you would implement a command with the appropriate permissions that allows you to start/stop the bot activity. For example I'd enable only myself to run the control commands.

Here's a nice way I would design the idea:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

is_active = True

@bot.check
async def isactive(ctx):
    if not is_active:
        await ctx.send(embed=a_nice_embed_showing_inactive_status)
        return
    return True

# the following essentially creates your own decorator to wrap control commands like start and stop.
def isme():
    def control_command(ctx):
        return ctx.author.id == my_id
    return commands.check(control_command)

@bot.command()
@isme()
async def stop(ctx):
    if not is_active:
        await ctx.send("The bot is already active!")
    else:
        is_active = False
        await ctx.send("The bot is active now.")

@bot.command()
@isme
async def start(ctx):
    # exact opposite of stop

@bot.command()
async def random_command(ctx):
    # this will fail if not is_active

bot.run("token")
```